# Looking for books about causal discovery

Tags: references, causality

I am new in causal discovery. I am reading papers and other stuff about causal discovery, but couldn't get any good books or good information. Can anyone recommend the best book for causal discovery?

Answer (score 8):

Additionally, you might want to check:

- Peters, Janzing and Scholkopf, [Elements of Causal Inference.](http://web.math.ku.dk/~peters/elements.html)
- Spirtes, Glymour and Scheines, [Causation, Prediction, and Search](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262194406)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the two classics are

> Judea Pearl. (2000). *[Causality: Models, Reasoning, and Inference](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/)*.
>   Cambridge University Press.
>
> Judea Pearl and Dana Mackenzie. (2018). *[The Book of Why: The New
>   Science of Cause and Effect](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/WHY/)*. Basic Books.

Answer (score 0):

I found additional books on causal inference. The only one of these that are on the sub-field of causal discovery might be the one that has discovery in the name.

[image: Cut-and-pasted from my notes]

Answer (score 0):

To get some basic concepts on causality (e.g. d-separation, confounding, causal sufficiency, stability, Markov equivalent class ...)

- Chapter 1,2 of Judea Pearl's <Causality: Models, Reasoning, and Inference>

To know the details of some classic causal discovery algorithms (PC, FCI, with and without causal sufficiency)

- Chapter 6  of Spirtes's <Causation, Prediction, and Search>
- Jiji Zhang's [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370208001008)